# Cancatenation of Multiple Flat files(.txt files) having variable name to a Single flat(.txt) file

Tags: shell, concatenation, flat-file

we want to concatenate multiple `.txt` files with Files names like `data_timestamp.txt` (as this file name will vary with timestamp) into a common file name like `data.txt` in the Unix shell scripting. Please assist in appending the files to single file.

i have tried with the below codes
    `cat > $STGFTPIN/'PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT'
     cat $FTPIN/'PRSNL_IDNTFCTN_*.TXT' > $STGFTPIN/'PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT'`

and as well
    `cat > $FTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT
     for i in $FTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN_*.TXT
     do
        cat i > $FTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT
     done
     mv $FTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT $STGFTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT`

Comment: `man cat`: `concatenate files and print on the standard output`

Comment: `        cat > $FTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT
  for i in $FTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN_*.TXT
  do
  echo i > $FTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT
  done

  mv $FTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT $STGFTPIN/PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT`

Comment: Also tried with the below code..........
`cat > $STGFTPIN/'PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT'
  cat $FTPIN/'PRSNL_IDNTFCTN_*.TXT' > $STGFTPIN/'PRSNL_IDNTFCTN.TXT' `